# Compare Greek (or other non-latin) strings in linq

Tags: c#, linq, entitymanager

I am trying to write a query in linq that returns results like this:

```
PeopleEntities pe = new PeopleEntities();
String fName = "Τάκης";
var people = pe.Person.Where(per => per.FirstName.Equals(fname)).ToList();
```

When I dump the query using

```
String query = ((ObjectQuery)pe.Person.Where(per => per.FirstName.Equals(fname))).ToTraceString();
Console.WriteLine(query);
```

and then using the query in a MySQL WorkBench providing a value, everything works fine but in code the query returns nothing.

Edit: I have connected entity manager by using a MySQL connector. I hadn't thought about it earlier but this is the problem as with an MsSQL connection everything works fine

Any ideas on how I can execute the above?

Comment: What about this `var people = (ObjectQuery)pe.Person.Where(per => per.FirstName.Equals(fname)).ToList();`. Does works it normal?

Comment: What about `==` instead of `Equals`? It doesn't work too?

Comment: How would casting a list to an ObjectQuery would help? It is not even allowed.

Comment: i've tried the same code with a diffirent object, it runs normally

Comment: Seddik, it runs fine when the alphabet is in a latin-based language, just not in Greek. Did you execute the code in such?

Comment: i've tried it with Τάκης

Comment: That is weird, I still can't manage to execute it right. When for example I used  per.FirstName.StartsWith("Γ")) it returned all starting with G and none with the greek letter Γ (Gamma)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a regionally-sensitive query, you should not use `string.Equals()` without providing a [StringComparison](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison.aspx) value, e.g.:

```
var people = pe.Person.Where(
    per => per.FirstName.Equals(fname, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Yes, this overload is supported in L2E.

If that still does not work, it is possible that the AppDomain's current culture or the DB's collation is wrong. Look at the query/params in SQL Profiler.

Comment: No this does not work either. I mean it does compile but it does not return a thing.

Comment: I also checked the collation and it is set in greek. If the collation was wrong it would not work from other languages such as php (which it does)

Comment: Read the rest of the post. You need to look at the actual SQL and see which part isn't right. Specifying the culture is the correct thing to do for the LINQ. As for the location of the rest of the problems you're experiencing, I can't infer them from what you've written in your post. Your LINQ is only part of this chain.